# React Native - using Crypto functions on android

Tags: android, react-native, cryptography

I need to decrypt files on android in a react native app.
The files are encrypted using node crypto 'createCipheriv'.

Is it possible to decrypt files fast in react native?

I tried using [browserify](https://www.npmjs.com/package/browserify) to convert the node crypto to browser usable code, but its way too slow. (5 seconds to decrypt a file)

I also checked 'react-native-crypto' but its deprecated and the solution they provide, 'crypto-browserify' does not work.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this package https://github.com/margelo/react-native-quick-crypto it is based on JSI and works like a native solution.

```js
const plaintext =
        '32|RmVZZkFUVmpRRkp0TmJaUm56ZU9qcnJkaXNNWVNpTTU*|iXmckfRWZBGWWELw' +
        'eCBsThSsfUHLeRe0KCsK8ooHgxie0zOINpXxfZi/oNG7uq9JWFVCk70gfzQH8ZUJ' +
        'jAfaFg**';
      const cipher = crypto.createCipheriv('des-ede3-cbc', key, iv);
      let ciph = cipher.update(plaintext, 'utf8', 'hex');
      ciph += cipher.final('hex');

      const decipher = crypto.createDecipheriv('des-ede3-cbc', key, iv);
      let txt = decipher.update(ciph, 'hex', 'utf8');
      txt += decipher.final('utf8');

      assert.strictEqual(
        txt,
        plaintext,
        `encryption/decryption with key ${key} and iv ${iv}`
      );
```

Comment: I get the error "The package at "node_modules\cipher-base\index.js" attempted to import the Node standard library module "stream"."

Comment: probably it is related to your environment (browsereify), try to test it on fresh project

Comment: it does not work even with a clean project created with create-expo-app. Do you know how to fix it? (you have to add import crypto from "react-native-quick-crypto" for the error to show)

Comment: Have you setup it https://github.com/margelo/react-native-quick-crypto#replace-crypto-browserify

Comment: I have the same babel.config.js except for the preset which does not matter for this. Should I manually install the packages they mention? ('stream-browserify', '@craftzdog/react-native-buffer

Comment: it means you have libraries which depends on crypto?

Comment: I tried downloading the packages mentioned in babel.config.js and it does not work. Im not sure what is the problem since the project is just a create-expo-app. I use nothing but react-native-quick-crypto in my project.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250457/discussion-between-user15329314-and-kirill-novikov).

Comment: I dont know why, but after restarting the computer it worked. Thank you